# Fix SQL Query with SELECT CASE / AND COUNT CASE

Tags: sql, postgresql

The following SQL query is not working, it returns error:

[42601] ERROR: subquery must return only one column Position : 50

I would need to fix it for a live project, and am having difficulties with it.

```
SELECT CASE WHEN habilitation.actif IS TRUE THEN (SELECT vue_cdc_for_opera.libelle,
                                                          dt_bdd_produit.libelle_dt,
                                                          vue_cdc_for_opera.classe_ue,
                                                          vue_cdc_for_opera.code_cdc,
    COALESCE(vue_cdc_for_opera.signe_ue, vue_cdc_for_opera.signe_fr),
    COUNT(CASE WHEN cdc_postgresql.id = habilitation.id_cdc_postgresql THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as operateurs
    )
        ELSE (SELECT vue_cdc_for_opera.libelle,
                      dt_bdd_produit.libelle_dt,
                      vue_cdc_for_opera.classe_ue,
                      vue_cdc_for_opera.code_cdc,
                      COALESCE(vue_cdc_for_opera.signe_ue, vue_cdc_for_opera.signe_fr))
        END
FROM vue_cdc_for_opera, cdc_postgresql, dt_bdd_produit, operateur, habilitation;
```

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: What part of the error message do you not understand?  The error seems quite clear.  If you want a query that works, you should provide sample data, desired results, and an explanation of the logic you want implemented.  Also, is there a reason you eschew proper, explicit, **standard**, readable `JOIN` syntax?

Comment: I understand the issue but I don't understand how to obtain what I want to achieve, which is basically get a SELECT and SELECT CASE returning a single table. The relations of this projects are a bit too tricky to provide sample data and desired result, so I thought maybe someone would spot something obvious. There is a reason, which is I'm not as good as I'd like in SQL. Thanks

Comment: . . And what I'm saying is that you need to explain what you want to achieve **in the question**.  That is the job of the person asking the question.  Sample data and desired results are really helpful for that.

Comment: Okay, no worries. When habilitation.actif returns true I would like to achieve is to recover a single table that countains all the properties nested in the (SELECT..), as well as the COUNT that also uses a case. When this column returns false I would like to just recover the table that is shown after the ELSE( SELECT..).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well it is very unclear what is you want to do but here it is what I can help you with:

In this example if `habilitation.actif` is *true* then you will select count of... and if it is not then you will select value `0` for that row. Please note that you have to use a group by when you use aggregation functions. Also you need to connect this tables from your `from` clause in someway... for more serious help add more details in your question, data also...

```
SELECT vue_cdc_for_opera.libelle,
       dt_bdd_produit.libelle_dt,
       vue_cdc_for_opera.classe_ue,
       vue_cdc_for_opera.code_cdc,
       COALESCE(vue_cdc_for_opera.signe_ue, vue_cdc_for_opera.signe_fr),
       CASE WHEN habilitation.actif IS TRUE THEN 
            COUNT(CASE WHEN cdc_postgresql.id = habilitation.id_cdc_postgresql THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)
            else 0      
       END a
FROM vue_cdc_for_opera, cdc_postgresql, dt_bdd_produit, operateur, habilitation
group by vue_cdc_for_opera.libelle,
       dt_bdd_produit.libelle_dt,
       vue_cdc_for_opera.classe_ue,
       vue_cdc_for_opera.code_cdc,
       vue_cdc_for_opera.signe_ue, 
       vue_cdc_for_opera.signe_fr,
       habilitation.actif
```

Comment: Thank you. I apologise for the broad question and appreciate you and Gordon's time. This should be enough to get me in a lead to make this query work.

Comment: If it helped I am very happy and you are welcome.You can mark this as correct and give it an up vote. Good luck.

Comment: The query is being run but don't recover any record, so it works, I'm sure if I tweak it progressively I will be able to reach my goal. Cheers

Comment: Great, now do as in my answer. Find a relationship between two tables (sometimes it is an id column and sometimes it is more than one column)  and join them. I recommend to join one by one and see your results after every one you have joined and then do the next one (be aware there are all sorts of joins depending on your needs ...)

Comment: The query now works with proper relations, thanks again